# Script to change desktop background

Tags: script, mail-server

Say I want to email my Pi a picture, and have it set the latter as it's desktop background. Say that I also already have the script that makes it pull the mail from GMAIL and launch a python script. The missing piece is the actual changing of the background.

Comment: What graphical environment does your PI run? Stock LXDE?

Comment: There's also [some example code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550895#25258008) valid for Gnome on Stack Overflow, as a base.

Comment: I installed raspbian and did no serious modifications

Answer (score 3):

```
pcmanfm --set-wallpaper /point-to-new-wallpaper
```

[There's a catch](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?t=49672) though. With LXDE, setting the desktop wallpaper from the command line has been on the [TODO](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXDE_To_Do#PCManFM_.28file_manager.29) list for at least 5 years. You'll have to check whether it works or not.